# How to extract integer from dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame:

The original data is extremely messy with hundreds of columns and rows, mostly duplicates and I was able to clean it to the best of my ability but came to this roadblock. The data is now stored as such:

```
    col
0   [6, str]
1   [37, str]
2   [72, str]
3   [104, str]
4   [142, str]
5   [174, str]
6   [206, str]
7   [244, str]
...
```

Seems as if the data turned into a DataFrame containing Tuples of "[int , str]" as 1 column and N rows. I need just the "str" value to be the column name and the integers to be rows in the same order. End result will still be a 1xN DataFrame, but remove all the duplicate "str" values and store it only as a column header.

I need to do this for 3 separate "str" values contained within these files and append all 3 to one giant cleaned up DataFrame like so:

```
    str1, str2, str3 
0   int1, int2, int3
1   int1, int2, int3
2   int1, int2, int3
...
```

The script currently is able to seek out each separate str value but stores them all like the first example. I can figure out how to append them after, but how do I go about separating the integers?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer on my own, thanks anyways. Hope this helps for anyone looking for something similar, it was so simple too.

I turned the DataFrame into a list "f" then did:

```
for i in f:
    a.append(i[0])
```

Now I have the data I need stored in "a" and can manipulate it how I want. "a" and "f" being arbitrary examples of list names.